# the replace function requires 3 arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

im trying to add "Store" into reporting service as a parameter. this is my code:

```
DECLARE @Store      nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @Delimiter  char
DECLARE @x          XML

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Store') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Store

CREATE TABLE #Store
(
Store_No int
)

SET @Delimiter = ','
SET @Store = '3,38'
SELECT @x = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@Store, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)
INSERT INTO #Store (Store_No)
SELECT
    x.value('.','int')
FROM
    @x.nodes('/*') n(x)
```

this works when i put 1 number in such as 3, however, when I put 2 or more, it gives me error called "the replace function requires 3 arguments"

any idea how can i fix this? thanks alot!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 2 or more numbers...

Comment: i mean when i select 2,3 or 2,3,4,5,6 in reporting services

Comment: It looks like SSRS is passing @Store as '3','4','6' instead of 3,4,6. Is '@Store' a multi value parameter? Are you using JOIN or any other User-function on '@Store' before passing to the proc?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's your problem, it's working fine with longer sequences

```
DECLARE @Store      nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @Delimiter  char
DECLARE @x          XML

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Store') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Store

CREATE TABLE #Store
(
Store_No int
)

SET @Delimiter = ','
SET @Store = '2,3,4,5,6'
SELECT @x = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@Store, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)
INSERT INTO #Store (Store_No)
SELECT
    x.value('.','int')
FROM
    @x.nodes('/*') n(x)

    select * from #Store
```

Answer (score 1):

Fully agree with @Roman Pekar -

```
DECLARE 
      @Store NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @Delimiter CHAR(1)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Store') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Store

CREATE TABLE #Store (Store_No INT)

SELECT 
      @Delimiter = ','
    , @Store = '2,3,4,5,6'

INSERT INTO #Store (Store_No)
SELECT t.c.value('.', 'INT')
FROM (
     SELECT ID = CAST ('<t>' + REPLACE(@Store, @Delimiter, '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
) r 
CROSS APPLY ID.nodes ('/t') t(c)

SELECT * 
FROM #Store
```